# Properties of arrayed objects don't test equal to original value

Tags: javascript

Sorry about the terrible title--I tried.

I'm trying to keep a list of references to objects corresponding one-to-one with the elements on an HTML page with a given class. I can do this with a Map using the element as the key and my custom object as the value, but the objects already have a property referencing the element so I'm trying to strip the data duplication and just array the objects. However, what I thought was a simple task doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect.

I've even logged the objects that should compare equal and they appear to be the same.

Here's my minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="a-widget" class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var widgetsArr = new Array();
  var widgetsMap = new Map();

  function createWidget(element) {
      var widget = Object.create(null);
      widget.element = element;
      return  widget;
  }

  function initWidgets() {
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('widget');
      for (var i=0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
          widgetsArr.push(createWidget(elements[i]));
          widgetsMap.set(elements[i], createWidget(elements[i]));
      }
  }

  function getWidgetByElementFromArr(element) {
      widgetsArr.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
          if (item.element === element)
              console.log(item);
              return item;
      });
  }

  function getWidgetByElementFromMap(element) {
      var widget = widgetsMap.get(element);
      console.log(widget);
      return widget;
  }

  initWidgets();
  console.log(widgetsArr[0]);
  console.log(widgetsArr[0] === getWidgetByElementFromArr(document.getElementById('a-widget')));
  console.log(widgetsMap.values().next().value);
  console.log(widgetsMap.values().next().value === getWidgetByElementFromMap(document.getElementById
('a-widget')));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `forEach` will not cause the loop to terminate or return a value like you expected. It will always loop through the entire array and not return a singular value. Use `find` instead:

```
function getWidgetByElementFromArr(element) {
  return widgetsArr.find(function(item, index, array) {
    return (item.element === element);
  });
}
```

The other issues with that function: It does not have a `return` statement. And there are missing `{` and `}` around the `if` body.

**Note** that `find` is not supported everywhere, so use a polyfill or use `filter(()=>{...})[0]`, or some other workaround as you see fit.